# Common practice to name project directory which hold support scripts, configs, docs, etc for developers

Tags: coding-style, naming-conventions

I work with small set of projects so lack of knowledge about naming convention for directory in software project file hierarchy which desired to hold project development.

I look to well-known projects (like Firefox, GCC, binutils, Linux, Emacs, VIM, etc) and collect some common directories (comments written myself so they don't pretend to be true...):

- `examples` or `samples` to show practical usage of project in mini-scripts or mini-programs, or mini-configs.
- `scripts`, `support` - wrappers or copy of missing scripts/utilities to provide cross-environment build.
- `tools` - extra utilities to profile or debug project.
- `contrib` - user supplied scripts, configs, etc...
- `misc`, `etc` - uncategorised files (if you don't know the right place for it).
- `config`, `extra` - don't know...

While `src/`, `test/`, `build/`, `dist/`, `lib/` and  other directories naming convention dictated by prog-langs/platforms/frameworks etc, this directories seems common for all type of projects.

So I look for guide (official or unofficial) for naming convention for directories that hold support files for project.

Most essential distinct from regular project files that these file **isn't used** in project release **build**, or is used in rare cases.

**PS**. Someone can argue that this is not SO question. But I have **real** task to commit several scripts (sql script to dump menu from DB, script which dump url mapping for web-controllers, etc) and look for directory name that shoud hold these files...

**PPS**. My effort to collect conventions:

- http://tips.defun.work/devel-proj-files.html
- http://gavenkoa.users.sourceforge.net/tips-html/devel-proj-files.html (mirror)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are:

- [The Software Package Data Exchange® (SPDX®)](https://spdx.dev/)
- [GNU Coding Standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html)
- [Maven Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)